# How do I roll a list or numpy array until a certain condition is met?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Here, for example, I want to roll the array until one (of the 1s) is at the start and then record what the shift was, but you could image some other arbitrary condition on the roll.

```py
arr_expected = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120])
shift_of_arr = ?
```

How do I roll the array until some condition is met?

Can it be done without a for loop and if so how?

For context: These are monotonically increasing values, but not necessarily with the same interval.

Thanks as ever!

Comment: Some questions: How huge is `arr` in your final application (more than `10k` elements?)? Is your only condition that the first `1` should be at position `0`? Do you have other _significantly_ different conditions?

Comment: `arr` is very small (say, < 100 elements). No other significantly different conditions in this case. Thanks @André!

Comment: @jtlz2 I modified your input to make it non ambiguous, can you update the output to ensure that you have what you want?

Comment: @mozway Just to check, in what sense it is ambiguous?

Comment: you had several times "1,2,3" so you could roll in either direction to end up with a 1 first ;)

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. So if I constrained it to roll forward (or backward) only until the condition is met, would that be doable?

Comment: @jtlz2 have you checked [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71031625/16343464)? This is what I did (rolling backwards)

Comment: Sure, but you've changed the input to something that I don't have?

Comment: @jtlz2 just for clarity, to discriminate the rolling order, obvious you can run it on **your input** with the same result ;)

Comment: @mozway As long as it still works - need to think about it. Perhaps you could add to your answer's NB to spell it out a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: @jtlz2 sure, done. Please let me know if anything is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NB. I slightly modified your input to make it non ambiguous (added 10 to the first values to be able to see the direction of rolling). Obviously the answer would work the same on the original data.*

You can use [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) on a boolean array to get the position of the first `1`, then use [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
arr = np.array([70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

n = np.argmax(arr==1) # 6
arr2 = np.roll(arr, -n)
```

output:

```
array([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,   1,
         2,   3,   4,   5,   6,  70,  80,  90, 100, 110])
```

Comment: Good catch with the ambiguity. Was just about to post the same answer but with `np.roll(arr, n)`! :-)

Comment: @André yes, hopefully OP will edit the question to make it unambiguous, but now the logic is there and the change is trivial ;)

Comment: @mozway Just to check, in what sense it is ambiguous?

Comment: @jtlz2 The only issue was that both rolling by `-6` **and** rolling by `6` indices resulted in the expected output, which is quite unfortunate. I almost submitted an answer with a wrong sign in the `np.roll`, since I thought it did the right thing. But that's really just unlucky rather than a mistake of yours ;-)

Comment: @André if you remove the 120 in my example you'll see that `n` does not work, it should be `-n` ;) I removed it for clarity

Comment: @jtlz2 so is this what you wanted to do? let me know to update the question with the correct output

Comment: I think you are missing a 120?

Comment: @jtlz2 I removed it on purpose to have a non ambiguous example, but this does not matter for the real-life use, just run the same code, this is just to have a better example here